# Docker container with neo4j and password set

Tags: neo4j, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image which runs the Neo4j server and does not require the user to manually set the password on the initial access.

I have this as a Dockerfile

```
FROM neo4j:3.2
ADD setPassword.sh .
RUN ./setPassword.sh
```

which runs this script

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Start server
./bin/neo4j start

# Wait for it to start
while [ -z "$(grep 'Remote interface available' /var/lib/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log)" ]
do
    echo Waiting for neo4j to start
    sleep 1
done

# Set the password via REST
wget --header="Content-Type: application/json" \
     --post-data='{"password": "newPassword"}'    \
     http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password

# Shut down the server
./bin/neo4j stop

tail -f /var/lib/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log &
sleep 10
# EOF
```

The script starts the Neo4j server, waits for it to start and then uses the REST API to set the password.  After that, it shuts down the server and waits a bit to make sure that it is shut down so that anything in memory is flushed to disk.

The script appears to run without errors and I am able to create a new image.  However, when I run the image and connect with a browser, the password is still neo4j.

Looking at the output of `wget` with no arguments:

```
BusyBox v1.26.2 (2017-06-11 06:38:32 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
  [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
  [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

  --spider  Spider mode - only check file existence  
  -c        Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
  -q        Quiet
  -P DIR        Save to DIR (default .)
  -T SEC        Network read timeout is SEC seconds
  -O FILE       Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
  -U STR        Use STR for User-Agent header
  -Y on/off Use proxy
```

it looks like the `wget` in the base image does not support most standard `wget` options, including making a post request.

I also failed to figure out how to install the standard `curl` in the image:

```
bash-4.3# apk add curl
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.84815163.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.24d64ab1.tar.gz: No such filapk e or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  curl (missing):
    required by: world[curl]
```

`apk fetch` and `ask search` give similar errors about missing `tar.gz` files.

I do not have any attachment to using the REST api: I want something that I can build automatically and not have to reset the password when my program accesses the database.

I did have a problem in the past where changes made in the Dockerfile where lost because the base image did a `VOLUME` command on the directory that holds that changes, but it looks like only `/data` is exported and it does not appear to hold any authorization information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override the login-password in the docker file:

```
FROM neo4j:3.2
ENV NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/newPassword
```